# Docker file not found, but I can see it

Tags: docker

I am trying to Dockerize an application that has files in two directories:

```
BOTFILES/
  ...
ChatScript/
  BINARIES/
    LinuxChatScript64
  DICT/
  ...
```

In my Dockerfile, I copy each directory separately.

```
FROM alpine:3.9


# https://github.com/ChatScript/ChatScript
RUN mkdir /bot
COPY ChatScript/ /bot/ChatScript
RUN chmod +x /bot/ChatScript/BINARIES/LinuxChatScript64

COPY BOTFILES/ /bot/BOTFILES

WORKDIR /bot/ChatScript

EXPOSE 1024

CMD ["./BINARIES/LinuxChatScript64"]
```

The `chmod +x` works correctly, but when I try to run the container I get the following error:

```
standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
```

If I change the CMD line to `/bin/ash`, I can get a working terminal and see that the `BINARIES/LinuxChatScript64` file is there and has the execute permission. However, if I try to run it, even from the interactive terminal, I get `/bin/ash: ./BINARIES/LinuxChatScript64: not found`. So I can see the file, I can `cat` the file, but running the files just gets me a file not found error. What am I missing?

Comment: What is `LinuxChatScript64`? If it's a script as its name indicates, what is its `#!` shebang line?

Comment: It is a binary, not a script, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a binary, is it dynamically linked? It may be missing shared library dependencies. Check `ldd` on the host machine for a list.

If it's a script, is the script's interpreter installed? Alpine doesn't come with bash pre-installed, for instance, so scripts using it will fail with "not found":

```
$ docker run -it --rm alpine:latest /bin/ash
/ # echo '#!/bin/bash' > script
/ # chmod +x script
/ # ./script
/bin/ash: ./script: not found
```

```
/ # apk add bash
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/5) Installing ncurses-terminfo-base (6.1_p20190105-r0)
(2/5) Installing ncurses-terminfo (6.1_p20190105-r0)
(3/5) Installing ncurses-libs (6.1_p20190105-r0)
(4/5) Installing readline (7.0.003-r1)
(5/5) Installing bash (4.4.19-r1)
Executing bash-4.4.19-r1.post-install
Executing busybox-1.29.3-r10.trigger
OK: 14 MiB in 19 packages
/ # ./script
```

Comment: This has definitely helped identify the issue. Switching to ubuntu instead of alpine as a base works once curl is installed. Apparently it relies on curl, as well as some other things that ubuntu includes but alpine does not by default.